# Super Easy HTML5 song inquiry

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm currently enrolled in a computer programming course while trying to knock out my generals for a psychology degree. I found it odd that I was enrolled in this course in the first place, but I'm not one to complain. As I've missed this course a lot due to cross country and my job, I have missed much of the courses' information. I need some guidance for writing a simple children's song that uses loops and variables. I went with the birthday song. The issue I'm having is introducing these variables and loops where needed, which would be after the "dear" portion. I want to use the names John, Susan, and Jacob in that portion.

```js
 /*make your calls to the JavaScript Function here*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Happy Birthday</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor='#696969'>
  <h1 style="text-align:center; color: white">Happy Birthday</h1> 
  <p>
    <h4>Happy Birthday to you! <br> Happy Birthday to you! <br> Happy Birthday dear <br> Happy birthday to you! </p>
 
    </body>
    <audio src="Song.mp3" autoplay loop>

    </html>
```

I may have formatted this atrociously and I apologize for ineptly this is put together, but I'm running off of 4 days of almost a semesters' worth of class. Any help with this would be immensely appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe you should spend a few hours studying instead of asking people to do your college work. You may be busy but I'm guessing your course provides lots of help and documents that are available online. I'm sure you can take some time out of your busy day to read up. The best way to learn is to at least attempt to do it yourself. Here you haven't you've just given us some HTML code without attempting to solve it yourself.

Comment: Wasn't asking you to do it, I was more so asking for some guidance here. I'm lost and figured a programming community would be a good place to get directed in the correct direction. I have attempted to figure it out, but I'm not in the slightest tech savvy or proficient at this sort of work. I do appreciate the help though, thanks!

Comment: Just fyi in future at least have a go and people wont mark down your answer and help you more even if you are totally wrong

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing you want it to show the names, each at different times.. probably one by one in a sort of animation.

The trick here is to use two things:

1. A Few Javascript Timers
2. A special `<div> </div>`  area with a unique ID assigned.

What you do is:   set a few Javascript timers, each with a different timeout,  and have them each change the inner text of the div by using the div's ID to identify it.

Below is a hint for the 2nd part ...

**The rest you'll have to find out online or from other stackoverflow questions.**

Good luck!

```html
<h4>
   Happy Birthday to you! 
     <br> 
   Happy Birthday to you! 
     <br> 
   Happy Birthday Dear: <div id="customNameArea"></div>
     <br>
   Happy Birthday to you!
</h4>
```